# case sensitive select query in mysql

Tags: mysql

Here Problem is make sql query is not check case sensitive latters
Here SQL Version;

```
 VERSION(): 8.0.15
```

Sql Query for login user:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM accounts WHERE (number = 'AdMin' OR email = 'AdMin') AND password = '******' AND type IN (1) AND deleted = 0
```

Database store name='admin'

here how to set case sensitive sql query for mysql 8.0 and stop login when username ='AdMin'

Comment: So if the database value is `admin`, do you want to be able to login with `AdMin`? it's not clear from your question

Comment: if try with username='AdMin' it login in portal but i need that username is wrong that not login in portal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `BINARY` operator to make your search case sensitive:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt 
FROM accounts 
WHERE (number = BINARY 'AdMin' OR email = BINARY 'AdMin') AND password = '******' AND type IN (1) AND deleted = 0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=33457338317be122dc7890d80f5db1e1)